# Verilog: ERROR:HDLCompiler:806

Tags: verilog

The task was to create a 7 bit binary to bcd counter. However, with one of my modules, I am getting an error like

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "D:/Xilinx Stuff/Binary_BCD/prog_counter.v" Line 23: Syntax error near "input".

I just started this language and looking to get all the help with syntax I can. I looked around for simple errors like missing semi-colons but couldn't find any. Maybe a second set of eyes will help:

```
module prog_count_7(max_count, reset, clk, count_out)

input [6:0] max_count;
input reset, clk;
output [6:0] count_out;

// Wires/Registers required go here.
reg reset;
reg [6:0] max_count;


// 7-bit counter instance
count_7 counter_1(.enable(1'b1),
          .reset(reset),
          .clk(clk),
          .count_out(count_out));


// logic for Counter control
always @(enable or reset or posedge clk or count_out) begin
    if(reset == 1) begin // Reset Condition
        if(max_count >= 99) begin
            count_out = 99;
        end else if(max_count<99 & count_out <99 & max_count > count_out) begin
            count_out = count_out + 1;
            end
    end else if(reset == 0) begin
        count_out = 0;
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semi-column on the first line.

```
module prog_count_7(max_count, reset, clk, count_out) ; //<-- here
```

Also, the sensitivity list for your "Counter control" doesn't make sense. `enable` and `count_out` shouldn't be there. And `reset should be`negedge reset`. Ususally like so:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
```

It is recommended to use non-blocking (`<=`) when assigning flops.

---

Suggested coding for "Counter control"

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 0) begin // Reset Condition
        count_out <= 0;
    end
    else if (enable == 1) begin
        if (max_count >= 99) begin
            count_out <= 99;
        end
        else if (count_out < 99 && max_count > count_out) begin
            count_out <= count_out + 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem and for the additional corrections with its functionality as well! However the enable is basically like an on/off for the counter so shouldn't it be included there as well?

Comment: No, it should be the condition of an if statement. If it is in the sensitivity then the code will execute whenever value of `enable` changes.

Comment: Alright got it! Last question, part of my constraints is to essentially run the counter when reset is high, does this mean the sensitivity should be posedge reset ?

Comment: Your code says to reset the counter when `reset==0` so that is `negedge`. However your in-code comments and your actual code do not match up, I'm guessing your intent. I'm also assuming you want a asynchronous reset. If you want synchronous, then only the clock should be in the sensitivity list.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was confusing the reset and the enable. Thanks for all your help.